# Android Studio is turning white colors into black in dark mode

Tags: android, android-studio

Since yesterday my app automatically changes the colours from white to black when i am in dark mode.
How can I turn it off?

My other apps work as usual.

My style.xml is the same as in my other apps:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/black</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/black</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/black</item>
</style>
```

And my layout is the following:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

</FrameLayout>
```

[what it looks like on device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFhat.jpg)

[what it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLGex.png)

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. could you please provide us with some detail, perhaps your styles.xml file

Comment: I have the same problem!

Comment: @FelixAMarreroPentón did you find a solution! I have the same problem!

Comment: yes force the dark mode in all sytles, day an nitgh

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it by:

1. create values-night directory besides values directory
2. copy themes.xml from values directory to values-night directory